# No such table: Error in android

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I have made a database table for creating and inserting data. It is a "virtual table" that i have made for full text search. But when i run my app, warning is shown that "no such table found"..

Please help me. I am posting my Database file. Thanks in advance...

```
package com.search.wordfinder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.util.*;

public class DatabaseCreation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

String sString;
SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
String query;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wor.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "cpy_fts";
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE =  "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " USING FTS3" + "(" + "title TEXT, " + "author TEXT, " + "publisher TEXT, " + "edition TEXT, " + "content TEXT" + ")";

public DatabaseCreation(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try{
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        insertData("Operating System", "PeterGalvin", "Willey", "Eight", "An operating System (OS) is a collection of software that manages computer hardware resources and provides common services for computer programs.");
        insertData("Database Management System", "Korth", "McGraw-Hill", "Fourth", "A DataBase Management System (DBMS) is a software system that manages execution of users applications to access and modify database.");         
        } catch (Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseCreation.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + 
        oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ",which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
}

public void insertData(String ttl, String athr, String pub, String ed, String cnt)  {
    mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", ttl);
    values.put("author", athr);
    values.put("publisher", pub);
    values.put("edition", ed);
    values.put("content", cnt);
    mDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    mDatabase.close();
}

public ArrayList<String> queryDatabase(String id){
    sString=id;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    query = "SELECT title,author,publisher,edition FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE content MATCH '"+sString+"'";
    Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(c.isAfterLast()==false){
            String str = "Title: " + c.getString(0) +"\n"+ "Author: " + c.getString(1)+ "\n" + "Publisher: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                    "Edition: " + c.getString(3);
            data.add(str);
            c.moveToNext();
        }   
        c.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a warning or an error?

Comment: Its an error,not an warning. Please help.

Comment: @SubhajeetParia Why are you creating a virtual table ? Could you try without creating one ?

Comment: Actually with a virtual table, i can make a full text search of a column using the "MATCH" command which is very fast than the general "LIKE" command. I have to implement a full text search which is only possible using a virtual table. That's the main reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOur first line of onCreate tries to delete all rows from a table, but you haven't created the table yet.  That's causing the error.

Comment: No, its still not working if i remove the db.delete() method.
The error is--
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: cpy_fts (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT title,author,publisher,edition FROM cpy_fts WHERE content MATCH 'system'

Comment: Is the create statement succeeding?

Comment: yeah..it should be working..thats the way to create a virtual table for full text search in SQLite.. I'm sure the statement is right.

Answer (score 0):

First error i see is:

```
db.execSQL("Drop table if exists" + TABLE_NAME);
```

Please replace to

```
db.execSQL("Drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
```

in onUpgrade method.

Then can you please post tell the line of the error? Or better post LogCat